# Elasticsearch termvector API not working

Tags: elasticsearch, vector, term-vectors

I've set the mapping the title field for the article type for the `testindex1` index as follows:

```
PUT /testindex1/article/_mapping
{
  "article": {
    "type": "object",
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true,
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "_index": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

omitting the remainder of the mapping specification. (This example and those that follow assume the Marvel Sense dashboard interface.) testindex1 is then populated with articles, including article with id 4540.

As expected,

```
GET /testindex1/article/4540/?fields=title
```

produces

```
{
   "_index": "testindex1",
   "_type": "article",
   "_id": "4540",
   "_version": 1,
   "exists": true,
   "fields": {
      "title": "Elasticsearch is the best solution"
  }
}
```

(The title text has been changed to protect the innocent.)

However,

```
GET /testindex1/article/4540/_termvector?fields=title
```

produces

```
No handler found for uri [/testindex1/article/4540/_termvector?fields=title&_=1404765178625] and method [GET]
```

I've experimented with variants of the mapping specification, and variants of the termvector request, so far to no avail. I've also looked for tips in official and non-official documentation, and on forums that cover Elasticsearch topics, including Stack Overflow. [elasticsearch.org](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) looks authoritative. I expect I've misused the termvector API in a way that will be instantly obvious to people who are familiar with it. Please point out my mistake(s). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this outside of Marvel Sense e.g. Curl? It's working fine for me. What version of ES are you using?

Comment: I've tried GET _termvector with curl. It produced the same "no handler" result. The ES version is 0.90.13.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.0 Beta and the term vectors API works. Thanks very much for answering this.

Comment: `GET /testindex1/article/4540/_termvectors` (ending with `s`) -- if anyone lands here because of the `no handler .. for url` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _termvector api endpoint for returning term vector stats was only added in the 1.0 Beta - you will need to upgrade if you want to use term vectors.

> **Term Vectors**
>
> Note
>
> Added in 1.0.0.Beta1.
>
> Returns information and statistics on terms in the fields of a
>   particular document as stored in the index.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html